# Altium Shortcut to cycle through all PCB layers one by one

Tags: pcb-design, altium, pcb-layers

I wonder if there is any shortcut in Altium to cycle through all layers of a multilayered PCB one-by-one? That is to say that when the shortcut is first entered 'Single layer mode' is selected and only one layer is displayed first and then when the shortcut is entered again then the next layed is displayed in 'Single layer mode'.. and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Altium documentation](https://www.altium.com/documentation/altium-designer/interactive-routing-ad?version=18.1):

> There are two approaches to interactively change layers during
> routing:
>
> - Press the * key on the numeric keypad. Each press of that key will move you down to the next available signal layer.
> - Use the Ctrl+Shift+Wheel Scroll shortcut combination. Hold Ctrl+Shift, then scroll the mouse wheel forwards to move down through
>   the available signal layers, scroll the mouse wheel backwards to move
>   up through the available signal layers. Note that this shortcut can be
>   used at any time to change layers, if you are not currently routing
>   then this shortcut combination will step through all enabled layers.

This does not only work during routing, but you can use these methods any time.
While `*` brings you one layer down, `Shift + *` goes one layer up.

Comment: Is there any way to remap these shortcuts? The usual window doesn't have NextSignalLayer operation listed.